# What is the release schedule of the Digimon Adventure tri. movies?

Tags: digimon-tri

The first movie of the series, Digimon Adventure tri. Saikai was released on 2015-11-21, with a retail release of 2015-12-18. This movie consisted of 4 episodes, and is the first part of a 6-movie (or 24 episode) series<sup>[1](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2015-05-06/digimon-adventure-tri-is-6-part-theatrical-anime-with-new-cast/.87876)</sup>.

According to an Anime News Network [article](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/daily-briefs/2015-11-22/digimon-adventure-tri.s-2nd-film-to-open-on-march-12/.95659), the second part of the series of movies will premier on 2016-03-12 in Japanese theaters; they also list the Crunchyroll release as March 2016.

Originally, I had heard that these movies will be released once a year for 6 years. However, that would make the final chapter have a release date of 2021. Is there any information regarding the schedule of release for this series of movies?

Answer (score 1):

Crunchyroll has released some information pertaining to the Digimon Adventure tri. movies.

Information from [Crunchyroll post](http://www.crunchyroll.com/anime-news/2016/01/15-1/video-digimon-adventure-tri-part-two-previewed-and-part-three-scheduled):

> Plans are being lined up for the second part of Digimon Adventure Tri: "Ketsui" (Determination), which opens for a limited theatrical run on March 12, 2016. Mimi Tachikawa's Hitomi Yoshida and Joe Kido's Junya Ikeda will be presenting a preview at Shinjuku Wald 9 on February 11th. Along with the news is a preview, that revealed the big detail that finale, "Kokuhaku" (Confession) is scheduled for summer 2016.

According to this post, the finale will be released in summer of 2016. However, this seems unlikely due to the fact that the second part of this six-part series is just being released on March 12th. I will update this answer if they change the date of the finale.